# Converting int and long into string in Go

Tags: go

I have concurrent routine like this,

```
Routine 1()
{
for 30 times
Send string
}

Routine 2 (out <-chan string)
{
for
case str := <- out:
        fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Now, I want to send from routine 1 string like, string + int + string + system time in nanosecond. Can anybody help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: I am actually asking, is it possible out <- string + strconv.Itoa(int) + string strconv.Itoa64(time.Nanoseconds()) in Go ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, I asked it too early. It is possible like this:

```
out <- string + strconv.Itoa(int) + string + strconv.Itoa64(time.Nanoseconds())
```

Thanks.

---

Update (Go1): `strconv.Itoa64` has been replaced by `strconv.FormatInt`.

Comment: Or like this: `out <- fmt.Sprintf("blah %d blah %d", someint, time.Nanoseconds())`